# How to execute an interactive shell program from a PHP webpage

Tags: php, shell, exec, interactive

Let's say I have a local webpage, that when a button is pressed, executes a program in C. I already can do that. The problem is that this program outputs logs and needs input from the user. My question is: how can I display bash-like window and run this program through it, so that output and input is seen through the screen?

Comment: Wouldn't SSH be a much more safe/secure/practical/easy method of accomplishing this?

Comment: why not parse the program output back to php and show on screen(browser). I would stick to  C distribute the full program as c (exe) whats the value in php and C? the c program has to be distributed to the user in any case.

Comment: perhaps knowing what the c does and what the php does would help

Comment: I just want to open the terminal in another window. It doesn't have to be displayed on a webpage.

Comment: @gvalero87 that doesn't say way the c program does or even why there's a need for php in the first place.

Comment: @Dagon I hava local web page to as my interface. Just like router's webpages, only that this is local. What I want is that when pressed a button the program starts on a terminal, but it doesn't have to be on the same webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I develop plugin for jquery ["Terminal Emulator"](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/) you can check this out. If you write your C program as JSON-RPC you can create your terminal with one line of javascript.

The other solution is to not use PHP at all, and creating your code as CGI written in C or even in Bash.

**Update:** You can modify your program to be CGI script

```
int main() {
  printf("Content-Type: text/plain\n\n");
  // code of your program here
}
```

and put it in cgi-bin directory and run it through browser http://yourserver.com/cgi-bin/program it display the output in browser

Comment: What you proposed is beyond what i thought. I just wanted to open up terminal in another window. It didn't have to be on a web page. Although I like your idea much much better. this is for my thesis project so if I can do it in short time I'll do it. In any case, do you know how to do it as I thought?

Comment: You can use this snippet http://wklej.org/id/472868/ but it don't handle directory traversing it just execute the code from 'QUERY_STRING' and it's not secure, no password check.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [ajaxterm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/), and specify the program that you want to run as the shell:

```
ajaxterm.py --command=/your/command --port=yourfavoriteport
```

You could redirect the user to the specified port, or display the terminal via an iframe.